# Add object data when throwing an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I am coding a MVC 5 internet application, and I have a question in regards to throwing exceptions.

How is the best way to include object data when throwing an exception. I am wanting the exception to display specific object data when an email is sent to me when an exception occurs.

Some options I found:

- I see that there is a `public virtual IDictionary Data` property. I could manually add data to the `Data` property.
- I could also export the object data to an xml file and include this in the exception.
- I could also maybe use reflection to get all the object fields.

Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I would definitely go for the `Data` dictionary, since that is the closest to the actual exception. Also, it doesn't need access to the file system, etc. to work.

We use the `Data` dictionary ourselves a lot, and it helps to have a list of keys you, so you can easily reference the data again.

For example:

```
public const string SOME_KEY = "some_key";

Exception e = new Exception("some error");
e.Data.Add(SOME_KEY, someValue);

throw e;
```

Re-use it later:

```
object some_key = e.Data[SOME_KEY];
```

Comment: Does it last through entire application? I mean if I want to use e.Data[SOME_KEY] in another application. will it work? as per this I am not able to get it work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467683/passing-exception-data-between-two-applications

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is asking about object data so, in my opinion it should be like this (e.g. object of Customer class to be sent):

```
Customer customer = new Customer(){customer.id=1000};

Exception ex = new Exception($"Some custom error message");
ex.Data.Add("cus",JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer));
throw ex;
```

Extract customer object value from catch:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Customer customer =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(ex.Data["cus"].ToString());
}
```