# Passing exception data between two applications

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I don't know if this has been already answered or not. But, I am unable to find the example or cause of this problem.

Application 1:

```
 try
        {
                //Read request and check for the request header element from the soap request


                //validating request and salt
                ...here it might gets failed.
                _requestValidationService.ValidateRequest();
            }
 catch (Exception ex)
            {                              
                ex.Data.Add("Exception", "test");
                throw ex;
            }
```

Application 2:

```
 catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string aa = Convert.ToString(ex.Data["Exception"]);

                throw ex;
            }
```

I don't know what I am missing here. But **aa** seems to be always empty and `ex.Data.Count` is always zero.

I just want to pass one code between two applications without adding new class of an exception.

Note: These two applications are wcf calls.

[EDIT1]

Application 1 validate request is the `IDispatchMessageInspector` `AfterReceiveRequest`

Comment: Wait, are you trying to throw an exception in one application and then catch it in another one?

Comment: Yes, in short I am passing data if exception is occurred.

Comment: And how exactly do you pass it?

Comment: You should answer rs232's question first before we can say anything useful about this.

Comment: @rs232, I not passing it there are two applications, WCF service 
Application 2 request for something application 1 serves it. when exception occurs I want application 1 to send the extra data.which I am unable to receive in application 2.

Comment: I am not passing it its a default behavior which goes into `catch`

Comment: I added more information to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions are not propagated to clients from a WCF service.  Instead, a SOAP Fault (assuming you are using SOAP) will be sent to the client.

You can [include exception details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649234.aspx) in the SOAP Fault, but in general it is not recommended to do so in production.

IMHO a better approach is to implement [an IErrorHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler.providefault(v=vs.110).aspx) that provides the Fault with whatever data you want to send to the client, and also gives you the opportunity to log the exception server-side.

You can then catch `FaultException` on the client and have access to the data added by your custom error handler.

Comment: This looks helpful, thanks. Let me try and get back to you.

Answer (score -1):

The exception class is designed by one throw / catch pair. If you should add any additional information to a cached exception, use the inner exception feature by the rethrow technique:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
     ErrorHandling.WriteError(ex);
     var newEx = new MyException("Additional message", ex) // wrap the original exception instance.
     newEx.Data.Add("Exception", "test");
     throw newEx;
}
```

After catching the wrapper exception you can find the original exception in the InnerException property. Another advantage that the original and wrapper exceptions contain their own stack trace so it is easier to find location of error source.

Comment: MyException is additional class which I don't want to add.

Comment: Ok. MyClass can be ApplicationException for example. The mentioned "rethrow" pattern can be used even with the base Exception class.